# On Coding Challenge Site Edabit I continuely get ERROR: Traceback unsure of what to do

Tags: python-3.x, traceback

For example on with this code I got ERROR:Traceback

```
      def verify_substrs(main_txt, head, body, tail):
full = head + body + tail
if main_txt == full:
    return "My head, body, and tail."
else:
    return "Incomplete"
```

```
FAILED: 'Incomplete' should equal 'Incomplete.'

ERROR: Traceback:
   in <module>

  File "./frameworks/python/cw-2.py", line 28, in assert_equals
    expect(actual == expected, message, allow_raise)
  File "./frameworks/python/cw-2.py", line 18, in expect
    raise AssertException(message)
cw-2.AssertException: 'Incomplete' should equal 'Incomplete.
```

I would really appreciate help because to me it seems the code should be working.

Comment: Looks like the site throws errors in cases of wrong answers. Which is weird, because a wrong output is not the same as an error. At any rate, you're missing a `.` (dot) at the end of `"Incomplete"`. See if that fixes it.

Comment: Thank you it did, Also thank you for explaining that traceback means I messed up.

Comment: ERROR means you messed up. The traceback is an explanation of the messup.

Answer (score 0):

> FAILED: 'Incomplete' should equal 'Incomplete.'

It wants "Incomplete." with a period at the end.